# How can I run created app in all Bada devices

Tags: bada

I have just created a new project with `Bada SDK 2.0.2`. When creating the new project I was asked to select a model i.e either HVGA, QVGA, or WQVGA.

Now my problem is that if I select a QVGA model than I am not able to run my app in HVGA and WQVGA. Similarly, if I select HVGA then also the same problem arises. So why does this happen? Do I have to create different projects for every resolution? If not how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your app in any resolution, irrespective of the resolution selected. Only thing is you need to take care of some UI changes which might occur due to resolution changes.
Moreover when you push you app to samsung app store, you need to select the device resolution for which you wish to publish.
Its entirely up to you.

Comment: I have simple create an helloworld application and the model i selct while creating project is QVGA.It runs fine on emulator but when i try to run it on HVGA device it doesnt run..why this happen.

Comment: and in the consol it shows the following error The "COM4" port is closed.

Comment: Wave M is the HVGA device. do you have this?I mean its not released yet.
I guess you havent installed the drivers